# Magento cron jobs are not scheduling in the cron_schedule table

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, crontab

I have cron task in my custom module for sync data. Below is the code in my module config.xml

```
<config>
-------
<crontab>
        <jobs>
            <tal_intermediate_cron_product>
                <schedule><cron_expr>0 8 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>intermediate/observer::manageMagentoProducts</model></run>
            </tal_intermediate_cron_product>
            <tal_intermediate_cron>
                <schedule><cron_expr>0 9 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>intermediate/observer::manageSyncProducts</model></run>
            </tal_intermediate_cron>
            <tal_intermediate_cron_insert>
                <schedule><cron_expr>0 10 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>intermediate/observer::insertProducts</model></run>
            </tal_intermediate_cron_insert>
            <tal_intermediate_cron_manageorders>
                <schedule><cron_expr>0 11 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>intermediate/observer::manageOrderDetails</model></run>
            </tal_intermediate_cron_manageorders>
        </jobs>
</crontab>
</config>
```

But the issue is these cron jobs are not scheduling in the cron_schedule table. But when i set to 50mins these got scheduled. Can anyone tell me if there is any issue in my code. Or is there any other reason for that.

I am facing a huge problem because of this. Anyone can help me please. Thank You.

Comment: did you figure out the issue?

Comment: Hi Dchayka, was unable to solve the issue. I created the cron jobs from the cPanel :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure the cron is set on your server. Try the following command using SSH

```
#crontab -l
```

There should be your magento_root/cron.php file.

If not, then you need to edit the crontab. Use the following commands

```
#crontab -e       
(this will open crontab in your default editor)

*/5 * * * * wget -O  /dev/null -q path_to_magento_root/cron.php > /dev/null
(add this statement and save and close the file. 
This will check your magento cron.php after every five minutes)
```

Now, magento cron is set on your server.

I'd also recommend you this extension [AOE_SCHEDULLER](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html). This will help you monitoring all magento crons.